# boost::python: expose a C++ class to a python script embedded in a C++ app

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

I am successfully able to load a python script file and call a function within using `boost::python` in a C++ app.

In the boost python [EmbeddingPython](https://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python/EmbeddingPython) wiki there is a tip on [how to load a python module](https://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python/EmbeddingPython#Loading_a_module_by_full_or_relative_path).

```
namespace bp = boost::python;

bp::object import(const std::string& module, const std::string& path, bp::object& globals)
{
    bp::dict locals;
    locals["module_name"] = module;
    locals["path"]        = path;

    bp::exec("import imp\n"
             "new_module = imp.load_module(module_name, open(path), path, ('py', 'U', imp.PY_SOURCE))\n",
             globals,
             locals);

    return locals["new_module"];
}
```

I can successfully use this to import a python module (`test.py`)

```
int main()
{
    Py_Initialize();

    bp::object main    = bp::import("__main__");
    bp::object globals = main.attr("__dict__");
    bp::object module  = import("test", "test.py", globals);
    bp::object run     = module.attr("run");

    run();

    return 0;
}
```

Running the above code with a *hello-world* `test.py` script works fine:

**test.py:**

```
def run():
    print "hello world"
```

**Output:**

> ```
> hello world
> ```

### Exposing a C++ class to python:

However, I now want to expose a C++ class to that script.

```
struct Foo
{
    void f() {}
};
```

As per the `boost::python` documentation, I expose this class as follows:

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(FooModule)
{
    bp::class_<Foo>("Foo")
        .def("f", &Foo::f)
        ;
}
```

As per the instructions in the above-linked wiki, I can then import my `FooModule`, and store it in my `globals`:

```
PyImport_AppendInittab("FooModule", &initFooModule); 

...

bp::object Foo = bp::import("FooModule");
globals["Foo"] = Foo;
```

This import is done **prior** to importing my `test.py` script, and this `globals` object is the one passed to `bp::exec` when importing my script (ie: `Foo` *should* be in the globals dict which `bp::exec` exposes to my script when importing).

**However, for some reason my `Foo` module is *not* visible to `test.py`**

### Question:

How can I expose my `Foo` class to the `test.py` python script I am loading?

---

### Full working example:

#### `test.py`:

```
def run():
    foo = Foo()
    foo.f()
```

#### `main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/python.hpp>

namespace bp = boost::python;

bp::object import(const std::string& module, const std::string& path, bp::object& globals)
{
    bp::dict locals;
    locals["module_name"] = module;
    locals["path"]        = path;

    bp::exec("import imp\n"
             "new_module = imp.load_module(module_name, open(path), path, ('py', 'U', imp.PY_SOURCE))\n",
             globals,
             locals);
    return locals["new_module"];
}

struct Foo
{
    void f() {}
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(FooModule)
{
    bp::class_<Foo>("Foo")
        .def("f", &Foo::f)
        ;
}

int main()
try
{
    PyImport_AppendInittab("FooModule", &initFooModule);
    Py_Initialize();

    // get a handle to the globals dict    
    bp::object main = bp::import("__main__");
    bp::object globals = main.attr("__dict__");

    // import FooModule, and store it in the globals dict
    bp::object Foo = bp::import("FooModule");
    globals["Foo"] = Foo;

    // import the test script, passing the populated globals dict
    bp::object module = import("test", "test.py", globals);
    bp::object run = module.attr("run");

    // run the script
    run();

    return 0;
}
catch(const bp::error_already_set&)
{
    std::cerr << ">>> Error! Uncaught exception:\n";
    PyErr_Print();
    return 1;
}
```

#### `Output`:

> ```
> >>> Error! Uncaught exception:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "test.py", line 2, in run
>     foo = Foo()
> NameError: global name 'Foo' is not defined
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of trying to inject `FooModule` into the Python script from the C++ side, just register the module with `PyImport_AppendInittab` from the C++ side and then `import` it from the Python side:

```
import FooModule

def run():
    foo = FooModule.Foo()
    foo.f()
```

Comment: Note to anyone else looking at this, in doing the above, `bp::import("FooModule");` is no longer necessary. The call to `PyImport_AppendInittab` is all that is required to allow the script to import `FooModule`