# Is it possible to inject a module into an imported module's globals?

Tags: python

I have a file `hello.py` which has a function `hello()`

**`hello.py`:**

```
def hello():
    print "hello world"
```

I have another file `test.py` which imports `hello`, and calls the function.

**`test.py`:**

```
from hello import *

def run():
    hello()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

If I run `test.py` through python, it works as expected:

```
$ python test.py
hello world
```

Now, however, I edit `test.py`, and **remove the import statement**:

**`test.py`:**

```
def run():
    hello()    # hello is obviously not in scope here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

I introduce a 3rd file, `run.py`, which **imports both `hello.py` and `test.py`**

**`run.py`:**

```
from hello import *
from test import *

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Naturally **this does not work**, as `hello()` is not in `test.py's` scope.

```
$ python run.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 5, in <module>
    run()
  File "test.py", line 4, in run
    hello()
NameError: global name 'hello' is not defined
```

**Question:**

- Is it possible to *inject* `hello()` into `test.py's` scope from `run.py`, **without having `run.py` import `hello.py`**?

I'm happy using lower level functionality, such as the [`imp`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html) module, if that is what is required.

Comment: It's possible, but hiding your dependencies is never a good idea.

Comment: @wim leaving whether it's a good idea or not off the table for now, if it is possible, please could you share how?

Comment: @wim for context on why I'm looking for this, please see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41004393/boostpython-expose-a-c-class-to-a-python-script-embedded-in-a-c-app)

Comment: For the record, `from hello import *` _is_ importing `hello.py`. It's just not binding a name for the module itself in `run.py`'s globals. Following up with `import hello` would not involve a second import, it would just pull the already imported module from the cache.

Comment: @SteveLorimer: You've got things backward. Instead of having your C++ code inject a module into your Python script's globals, you should have your Python import the module exposed by your C++ code.

Comment: @user2357112 but how do I expose that module to the script? The module exists only in my c++ app. Or perhaps the call to `PyImport_AppendInittab(...)` makes it available to the script when I import it using `imp`?

Comment: "The module exists only in my c++ app." - no, that's not how module existence works. Python code running in your embedded interpreter should be able to import it just fine.

Comment: @user2357112 awesome, thanks! I tried to `import Foo` but got an `ImportError`, because I've registered it as `FooModule` with `PyImport_AppendInittab`. As such, `import FooModule` works. If you're interested in posting an answer in my other question I'll gladly accept

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. A module's attributes *are* its globals, so you can just poke it in there.

```
import test
import hello
test.hello = hello.hello
```

I'll reiterate wim's comment that this is generally not a great idea.

Comment: Man, as simple as that! Thanks! I completely understand this is not a good idea, so perhaps if you could look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41004393/boostpython-expose-a-c-class-to-a-python-script-embedded-in-a-c-app), and offer a superior solution, I would really appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

Modules are mutable:

```
import hello
import test

test.hello = hello.hello

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing sounds suspiciously like a *class.*  If it walks like a class, and it talks like a class, it's a class.

In `hello.py`:

```
class Hello(object):
    @classmethod
    def hello(class_):
        print("Hello, world!")
```

In `test.py`:

```
class Test(object):
    @classmethod
    def run(class_):
        class_.hello()
```

In `run.py`:

```
import hello
import test

class Run(hello.Hello, test.Test):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Note: we don't instantiate the class.
    Run.run()
```

This doesn't give you exactly the same syntax, and so it does not answer your question directly, but it gives you the same functionality you are looking for without resorting to unexpected hacks, like modifying other modules.

What I'm describing is not the *only* way to solve this, but having one module modify another module can be a fairly surprising way for your code to work.